# A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. (bucket already created)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-s3fs

Using s3fs, I am uploading a file to the already created s3 bucket (not deleting the bucket). On execution, the following error is thrown:

`[Operation Aborted]: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource.`

However, I would just like to dump the pickle file into the already existing bucket rather than creating a bucket for every dump.

Could not find a helpful answer in this regard.

Comment: Damn, having the same issue. It seems no solution yet. No bucket deletion, but multiple apps crashes because of that.

Comment: @aleks.n.fedorov, are using the fspec module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the wrapping of fsspec over s3fs which had a conflicting mk_dir argument. This was trying to create the bucket even after its existence in AWS.

Instead removed the the fsspec and directly used the s3fs module.

```
import s3fs
import pickle

file='abc.pkl'
s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem()
with s3.open(f's3:///{bucket_name}/{file}', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump('data_to_be_written', f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This mean the bucket was queued for deletion.

You must wait until its deleted until you can re-create it and upload

[aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-conflicting-conditional-operation/)

Comment: If you read me right, the bucket is neither deleted nor queued for deletion. It is always existing.

Comment: Sorry have you double checked the public access permission?

Comment: Yes, permission is available. My tasks are also getting stored initially but updating and saving my tasks on frequent attempts throws this error.